# How to change PHPMYADMIN SQL date as per the paypal return value of date

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, paypal

i have create custom paypal form with HTML variable and paypal return the payment date in this format
09:57:33 Feb 13, 2017 PST
but sql does not understand this format of date 
so what can i do so that SQL understand this format 
and if i put a condition like 
if i add any date in that paymentdate then result will be 
added date of payment date 
let me explain you.

like now paypal send me 
09:57:33 Feb 13, 2017 PST

what syntax of figures(7days) i will add to that format so that it return me

09:57:33 Feb **20**, 2017 PST

means after 7 days  that query return me 20th of feb

may be little confusing 
but i have tried to explain it as i can..
if want more explanation then i will explain it more..

Comment: You have to create a real date in order to calculate. What is your procedure the date is Feb 27 or Dec 31?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$date = "09:57:33 Feb 13, 2017 PST";
$date = strtotime($date );
echo date('h:i:s M d, Y',strtotime("+7 day", $date));
```